# Conversions between volatile, const, volatile const, and "neither" types

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, implicit-conversion, volatile

What does the C++(11) standard say about conversions among volatile, const, volatile const, and "neither" types?  I understand that it's well-defined and acceptable to assign a const type to a non-const and non-volatile type, but what about conversions among the following types (where T is some type)?

```
// T
T
T volatile
T const 
T volatile const 

// Pointer-to-T
T*
T volatile*
T const*
T volatile const*

// Volatile pointer-to-T
T* volatile
T volatile* volatile
T const* volatile
T volatile const* volatile

// Const pointer-to-T
T* const
T volatile* const
T const* const
T volatile const* const

// Volatile const pointer-to-T
T* volatile const
T volatile* volatile const
T const* volatile const
T volatile const* volatile const
```

---

As a simple example, consider the following code:

```
T volatile a;
T const b;

a = b; // implicit conversion from const to volatile; okay?

template<typename T>
void fcn(T& t)
{
    t = b; // implicit conversion from const to non-const, which I assume is okay
}
fcn(a); // implicit conversion from volatile to non-volatile; okay?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What can you assign to what?**

You can always assign volatile values to non-const values. You can also assign const and non-const values to volatile values. You can never assign anything to const values, because they're const.

**Does a conversion occur?**

No - it's just doing an assignment.

**Why is this?**

`volatile` means that any accesses to an object **cannot be optimized out**. There are actually very few cases where `volatile` is ever needed, or used. These cases are:

- When you're timing an operation, and don't want the calculation to be optimized out (Please use a benchmarking library for this. Don't roll your own)
- When you're doing memory mapped IO. In this case, you want to guarantee that reads and writes aren't optimized out, so volatile can be used.

Because of this, it must be possible to assign `volatile` to regular objects and vice versa. At the same time, however, volatile references *shouldn't* be implicitly converted to regular references, because that would potentially lead to reads and writes being optimized out.

**What about const?**

You can assign const stuff to anything, but nothing can be assigned to const (because it's const).

Comment: Other cases for ```volatile```: interrupt service routines (ISRs), or any other independent threads/processes a given program is unaware of that may touch a variable (e.g. host-side application that talks to embedded target processor).

Comment: For your memory mapped IO example, it seems odd that attempting to read a byte would be optimized out? How does that work?

Comment: @JoeManiaci As one example, if the MMIO register is only written to via "hardware", and only ever read from the program (perhaps beyond setting some initialization value), then the compiler could just return a constant or the initial value of the register every time instead of actually loading the contents from the register.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> a = b; // implicit conversion from const to volatile; okay?
> ```

Whether it is "okay" depends on the type `T`.

What happens here is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This is what the standard rules say:

> [conv.lval]
>
> A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue. If T is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.
>   If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T.
>   Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is T.

So, if for example `T` is not a class type, then the prvalue of the conversion from `T const b` will be a `T`, which is the same as the type of the assigned variable in this case. So, as long as `T` is assignable (i.e. not const), it is "okay".

For class types, whether the assignment is "okay", depends on what kind of assignment operator(s) the class has. The implicit assignment operator is not volatile qualified, so the example assignment would **not** be "okay". It would be ill-formed. But it is possible to have a user declared a volatile qualified assignment operator, although this is quite uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `fcn(a); // implicit conversion from volatile to non-volatile; okay?`, that is not okay according to [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP32-C.+Do+not+access+a+volatile+object+through+a+nonvolatile+reference), since it will result in referencing a volatile type from a non-volatile type:

> The C Standard, 6.7.3 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011], states
>
> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

---

Also, although I don't have a reference, I believe that assignment and conversions among pointers must have the same volatile-/const- qualified type that they point to (i.e. the `const`s/`volatile`s  before the `*` must match):

`T volatile* volatile t;
T volatile* volatile const t1 = t; // okay; initializing const with non-const
T* volatile t2 = t; // not okay; t and t2 point to different types
T volatile const* volatile t3 = t; // not okay; t and t3 point to different types`